# Invalid <drawable> for given resource value

Tags: android

I'm facing an error in Android Studio (Java). I'm not able to identify what exactly the issue is. I need your help in this issue.
In values.xml file
#0cffffff
(Android studio is giving error in this line)
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Piulx.png)
[Error line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXB2U.png)
The error description is

> Task :app:mergeDebugResources
> C:\Users\HP.gradle\caches\transforms-3\084db92e5b72338878ef5c863c3c2a34\transformed\core-1.9.0\res\values\values.xml:31:4: Invalid  for given resource value.

> Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ResourceCompilerRunnable
> Resource compilation failed (Failed to compile values resource file D:\CampSahulat2\app\build\intermediates\incremental\debug\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml. Cause: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@38313088.). Check logs for more details.

I'm unable to find the error. How can I identify it

Answer (score 1):

You need to use  tag for defining any color resource.
So replace

```
<drawable name="notification_template_icon_low_bg">#0cffffff</drawable>
```

with

```
<color name="notification_template_icon_low_bg">#0cffffff</color>
```

then clean build and rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

it is a color resource, not a drawable resource.

Answer (score 0):

If you want color, use colors.xml for easy reference. In that

```
<color name="color_name">#0cffffff</color>
```

Answer (score 0):

So what you are doing here is using a drawable tag for a color resource.

**1.If you want a color resource you can do it by creating a new tag under** `res\values\color`.

[image: color resourcle file]

**2. If you want to add that color as a drawable then you need to create a drawable file under `res\drawable`. which will look like this.**

[image: drawable path image]

this is a drawable file example where you can add colors.

[image: drawable file exampple]